# Find all tasks associated with buildType?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the android experimental plugin 0.4 ( gradle 2.8 ) and would like to modify all tasks that are associated with a buildType; debug in my case.

Currently, I am using the following "hack":

```
tasks.all {
   if( it.name.contains("Debug") ) {
     print it.name
   }
}
```

Is there a more typesafe way ?

Comment: Why is this a hack?  You might need to wrap it in an `afterEvaluate` closure to ensure the `hack` runs after all tasks have been configured, but that depends on what you are doing to create the tasks

Comment: The names of the tasks of the ndk are quiet long. I am looking for something more stable, since I want to disable the strip debug symbols tasks of the debug build type.

Comment: I would love to hear how you disable debug symbol stripping...

Comment: It only worked for one specific version of the plugin. However, i never wasn't able to get the code into a state where I would be able to debug it on the device via AndroidStudio. I hope some of the next updates will improve on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about this specific plugin, but a better way to do this with the Gradle API might be:

```
tasks.withType(AndroidTask).all {
  print it.name
}
```

Where AndroidTask is a *Class* reference. You'll have to look at the sources of the plugin to figure out the exact class. They also provide `tasks.matching {}`. Check out the [TaskCollection GroovyDocs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html#withType(java.lang.Class)) for specific usage.

Comment: This will allow to filter for a specific task. However, i need to find which of these tasks are associated with a certain buildType. (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html )